# Running Nemo errors with: Settings schema 'org.nemo.preferences' is not installed

Tags: arch-linux, nemo, gsettings

I am trying to replace Nautilus with Nemo on my Archlinux system.

I followed this guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo

I was able to install Nemo via pacman but when I try to start Nemo I get the error:

```
[jet@jetArch /etc]$ nemo

(nemo:7863): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.nemo.preferences'  is not installed

[1]    7863 trace trap (core dumped)  nemo
```

I can successfully see the version of nemo though:

```
[jet@jetArch /etc]$ nemo --version
nemo 3.0.5
```

So nemo is installed. But:

```
[jet@jetArch /etc]$ gsettings list-schemas | grep nemo
```

returns no results, so I guess no schema for nemo.

In the */usr/share/applications* there are the *.desktop* files

```
[jet@jetArch applications]$ pwd
/usr/share/applications
[jet@jetArch applications]$ ls *nemo*
nemo-autorun-software.desktop  nemo-autostart.desktop  nemo.desktop
```

But no *org.nemo.desktop*

```
[jet@jetArch applications]$ gsettings set org.nemo.desktop   show-desktop-icons true
No such schema 'org.nemo.desktop'
```

Nor

```
[jet@jetArch applications]$ gsettings set nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true 
No such schema 'nemo.desktop'
```

But if I open *dconf-editor* there is an entry for *org.nemo.desktop* as well as *org.nemo.compact-view*, *org.nemo.icon-view*, etc.

So why can dconf-editor find the nemo schema but nothing else can, including nemo.

Thanks for any help.

P.S.
Running *nemo* as root did not help:

```
[jet@jetArch applications]$ sudo nemo
[sudo] password for jet: 

(nemo:9909): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(nemo:9909): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.nemo.preferences' is not installed

[1]    9908 trace trap  sudo nemo

[jet@jetArch applications]$ sudo nemo -c
running nemo_self_check_file_utilities
running nemo_self_check_file_operations
running nemo_self_check_directory

(nemo:9922): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.nemo.preferences' is not installed

[1]    9921 trace trap  sudo nemo -c
```

Comment: Try upgrading your system with `pacman -Syu`.

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 That was the first thing I tried, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling nemo.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thanks for the help, your answer worked.

Comment: I've edited your question's title to be more generic and searchable.

Answer (score 3):

Confirm your system has the following file:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.nemo.gschema.xml
```

If so, run (as root):

```
# glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.nemo.gschema.xml
```

Comment: I had to specify the folder rather than the file itself: `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`